# Regex to check for a repeated Pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a text with a pattern where there are two constant letters (start, end) and in between them there can be any letter. For example if start is `X` and end is `Y`. Then I could have something like this:

```
ABCDXaYXpYXpYXlYXeYEFGHOASDASDADASD
```

Which is the word `apple` where each letter is sorrounded by `X` and `Y`

What would be the regex where I can match only the string `XaYXpYXpYXlYXe`? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, so I changed the focus of the question a little bit. Could you maybe help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer for the edited version. A bit of ugly trickery, but oh well.

```
var str = "ABCDXaYXpYXpYXlYXeYEFGHOASDASDADASD";
var regex = /(?<=[XY])(.*)(?=[XY])/;
var result = str.match(regex);
regex = /[XY]/g;
result = result[0].replace(regex, ""); // "apple"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either match anything that isn't X or Y (although it'll break it up into substrings):

```
var str = XaYXpYXpYXlYXeY;
var regex = /[^XY]/g; //case sensitivity optional
var result = str.match(regex) // ["a", "p", "p", "l", "e"]
```

or you could replace all of the X and Y with blank spaces.

```
var str = XaYXpYXpYXlYXeY;
var regex = /[XY]/g; //case sensitivity still optional
var result = str.replace(regex, ""); // "apple"
```

Comment: Sorry I changed the question just a minute ago. Could you maybe help me with that?